# jQuery Mobile Android 2.x slide transition support

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-transitions, slide, android-2.3-gingerbread, polyfills

jQuery Mobile doesn't support 3D transitions such as slide for Android 2.3 and lower.
There are some polyfill/widget/plugin/way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the reason these are disabled for older versions of android is lack of support for 3-D transitions in the android browser itself. Trying to implement this with some workaround will probably give you absolutely dismal performance. My best advice: stick with fade. Secondary advice that may or may not be useful, check out jQTouch to see if it may implement the transitions you're looking for. [jQTouch Site](http://jqtouch.com/)